# Is it correct to use the word "sideways" to mean "towards both sides"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

All dictionaries I checked say that “sideways” means “towards or from **one** side”, but I have the feeling that it can also refer to  “both sides”, for example.

> When I pressed the orange against the table it squirted juice sideways (both to the right and to the left)

or

> At my age I can only grow sideways (meaning that I grow fat towards both sides)

Is it correct to say so? If not, is there a better (single) word that can be used in the examples?

Comment: **sideways** means **laterally**.

Comment: What would it mean to say "Move that hexagon laterally"?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, your two examples are correct and show that "sideways" can mean "on all sides".  Pragmatic interpretation of context is used to get the meaning in each case.

In you examples "sideways" means "not up and down". On the other hand "Crabs walk sideways" means "Not forward or back".